# ST_ApproximateMedialAxis producing strange outputs

Tags: python, postgis, geometry

My problem is as follows: I have some lines (yellow), that I want to merge in one line if they are at a certain distance (blue, buffer), and after a long research I found [this](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.2/ST_ApproximateMedialAxis.html) function from PostGIS/SFCGAL. The output are the red lines. It kinda does the job, but it makes a strange angle when it joins the lines that I would like to get rid off. The function does not have parameters to tweak, so I wonder what else I could do. I do not want the skeleton, which I could find some help here, cause I dont want the line to be touching the borders of the buffer.

I work with python mainly, but open to suggestions.
[image]

[image]

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell without know what the input looks like and what you mean by it kinda works?

Comment: The input is the blue buffers. By kinda works I mean that the middle lines in the straight segments work, but in the union of two segments, instead of doing the shape of a Y, it does those strange 90 degrees angles.